# Where can one find the Bitcoin Dominance chart index?

Tags: coinmarketcap-com

Is there a chart where it shows how much market cap is bitcoin compared to the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can check it here: https://coinmarketcap.com/charts/

It shows the bitcoin market cap compared to the rest. You can click on the coins below the chart to enable disable them.

[image]